# Setting value of input type date in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, date

I'm trying to set the value in my input field of type date in my jsp page. The value is fetched from database is of type String(varchar) I want to set this date value to my input field.

My Jsp script is given below.

```
<%
      Op_Product opp = new Op_Product();
      String pubdate = null;
      ResultSet rse = opp.getOneProductWithId(request.getParameter("prdid"));
      while (rse.next()) {                            
             pubdate = rse.getString("prdf7"); // value to set to input field                            
      }
%>
```

My html input type date field is given below.

```
<input id="d-pubdate" type="date" class="form-control" name="pubDate" value="<%=pubdate%>"required>
```

The error I'm getting on this is "Bad value for attribute, The literal did not satisfy the date format".

The format is "YYYY-MM-DD".

Comment: convert it to date format in your jsp once you get it from the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSP, you can use [JSTL fmt tag library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) that provides a set of tags for parsing and formatting locale-sensitive numbers and dates.

Read more [Oracle Tutorial - Internationalization Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL6.html) and [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/)

Sample code:

```
<c:set value="10/23/2014 - 15:15:22" var="dateString" />

<fmt:parseDate value="${dateString}" var="dateObject"
                                      pattern="MM/dd/yyyy - HH:mm:ss" />

<fmt:formatDate value="${dateObject}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm a" />
```